# Installing .NET MAUI on Linux

Tags: .net, maui

```
dotnet workload install android
Unhandled exception: System.IO.IOException: Read-only file system : '/snap/dotnet-sdk/216/metadata'
   at System.IO.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(String fullPath, UnixFileMode unixCreateMode)
   at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Workloads.Workload.Install.WorkloadInstallerFactory.CanWriteToDotnetRoot(String dotnetDir)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Workloads.Workload.Install.WorkloadInstallerFactory.GetWorkloadInstaller(IReporter reporter, SdkFeatureBand sdkFeatureBand, IWorkloadResolver workloadResolver, VerbosityOptions verbosity, String userProfileDir, Boolean verifySignatures, INuGetPackageDownloader nugetPackageDownloader, String dotnetDir, String tempDirPath, PackageSourceLocation packageSourceLocation, RestoreActionConfig restoreActionConfig, Boolean elevationRequired)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Workloads.Workload.Install.WorkloadInstallCommand..ctor(ParseResult parseResult, IReporter reporter, IWorkloadResolver workloadResolver, IInstaller workloadInstaller, INuGetPackageDownloader nugetPackageDownloader, IWorkloadManifestUpdater workloadManifestUpdater, String dotnetDir, String userProfileDir, String tempDirPath, String version, IReadOnlyCollection`1 workloadIds, String installedFeatureBand)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.WorkloadInstallCommandParser.<>c.<ConstructCommand>b__6_0(ParseResult parseResult)
   at System.CommandLine.Invocation.InvocationPipeline.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<<BuildInvocationChain>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Parser.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<<UseParseErrorReporting>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.CommandLine.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<<UseHelp>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.CommandLine.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c.<<UseSuggestDirective>b__17_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.CommandLine.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<<UseParseDirective>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.CommandLine.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<<UseExceptionHandler>b__0>d.MoveNext()
```

I ran the following command to install the dot net sdk  : "sudo snap install dotnet-sdk --classic" , which installed dot net  sdk version 7 .I then tried running the above command  : ".Net workload install android"and found the above error as a result .I am using the Rider IDE.Any help on the same will be much appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Would these comments help? https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/4446#issuecomment-605629427

Comment: Microsoft's MAUI was designed without Linux in mind, so trying to work on the path you chose is only bringing you more trouble right now. Please use a Windows or Mac machine instead, and wait for future changes.

Answer (score 4):

That is because the Snap package manager creates read-only images of the things you install so it can't be tampered with. Also see here: https://askubuntu.com/a/919098

What worked better for me is installing .NET through the install script as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual#scripted-install

1. Download script

`wget https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh -O dotnet-install.sh`

2. Make it executable

`chmod +x ./dotnet-install.sh`

3. Execute

`./dotnet-install.sh --version latest`

This will install the latest version which might not be the LTS version. If you want the current LTS version, don't include any parameter.

Don't forget to add the path to your `DOTNET_ROOT` and `PATH` environment variables. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual#set-environment-variables-system-wide).

Assuming you're using Bash, open `~/.bashrc` and add

```bash
export DOTNET_ROOT=$HOME/.dotnet
export PATH=$PATH:$DOTNET_ROOT:$DOTNET_ROOT/tools
```

You might need to execute `touch ~/.bashrc` or start a new terminal window. Then you can now do `dotnet --info` and it should give you the .NET info.

To install the .NET MAUI workload run: `dotnet workload install maui-android`.

At the time of writing the out-of-the-box .NET MAUI project template doesn't build on Linux. This is because it tries to build the iOS and macOS targets as well. Fix it like this:

1. Open your csproj file and search for the `<TargetFrameworks>` tag. It will have 3 entries like `net7.0-android;net7.0-ios;net7.0-maccatalyst`. There is also one that has a `Condition` attribute on it for Windows, you can leave that one as is.
2. Change the `<TargetFrameworks>` tags to look like this:

```xml
<TargetFrameworks>net7.0-android</TargetFrameworks>
<TargetFrameworks Condition="!$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('linux'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-ios;net7.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
<TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

Note that where it says net7.0 it could also say net6.0 or net8.0 depending on the version that you're running.

Comment: that looks cool , i have managed to install it  as you said above , thanks.This one again comes with the following 3 problems :   Microsoft.NET.Sdk.ImportWorkloads.targets(38, 5): [NETSDK1178] The project depends on the following workload packs that do not exist in any of the workloads available in this installation: Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net6
You may need to build the project on another operating system or architecture, or update the .NET SDK.

Comment: (2)   Microsoft.NET.Sdk.ImportWorkloads.targets(38, 5): [NETSDK1178] The project depends on the following workload packs that do not exist in any of the workloads available in this installation: Microsoft.MacCatalyst.Sdk.net6
You may need to build the project on another operating system or architecture, or update the .NET SDK.  and (3)   Contacts.csproj: [NU1012] Platform version is not present for one or more target frameworks, even though they have specified a platform: net6.0-android, net6.0-ios, net6.0-maccatalyst.thanks for any response.

Comment: @KelvinKirwa updated the answer for actually building the .NET MAUI project